# When I hit the refresh, media queries changes min-width

Tags: css, reactjs, media-queries

So, in my case, I want to use a min-width 1281px query. If I go to directly /my-url mind-width works as I expect. If I choose it from the navbar, my container stays on min-width 1101px media query, when I hit refresh it comes to 1281px query which I want to use.

here are my related codes:

```
.container {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

@media (min-width: 1101px)
.container {
    width: 1101px;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 16px;
}

@media (min-width: 1281px)
.container {
    width: 1281px;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    padding: 0 8px;
}

.container, .content-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 1101px)
.container {
    width: 1101px;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    padding: 0 16px;
}

*, :after, :before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

user agent stylesheet
div {
    display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 1281px)
body {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```
main#
    width 100vw
    min-height 100vh
```

Comment: Why do you have `min-width 1101px` set, if you don't want to use it?

Comment: I guess It's coming from my main css element which I use width: 100vw and min-heigth: 100vh

Comment: So, can you not remove the two `@media (min-width: 1101px)`?

Comment: What is the actual width of the viewport? How does clicking something within the navbar change the width of the viewport? I would suspect that the styles for the 1281px media query override those of the 1101px media query. If you refresh the page only the 1101px styles are loaded.

Comment: When I refresh the page it loads 1281px strangely. actual width is 100vw

Comment: It's coming from another file to check screen width @Geshode

Comment: `vw` is a different unit, basically saying % of the total width of the viewport. How wide is the viewport in `px`?

Comment: It setted as 1 `width: 100%` @aside

Comment: Please check the width in pixels like so: https://pasteboard.co/K3OEP2I.png

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newb. it's 1101x1591.690 px @aside